# My Site pages are not indexed in google

Tags: seo

I created a site in codeigniter and it has many pages but they are not getting indexed in google search result.
Refer this page - 
[image]

There are many pages like this. The other pages are same with different location name. Can any body please help why google is not indexing my pages??

Answer (score -1):

It will take some time to index your pages.

If you are new to optimize the website do check:

[Basic Guidelines to optimize a website](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf)